# Newton method and Armijo-Goldstein

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, nonlinear, inverse

I need help with my project. I have three nonlinear systems and I need to write a code for Newton methods and Armijo-Goldstein and see the differences.

```
f[x1, x2, x3] = {x1^5 + x2^3*x3^4 + 1, x1^2*x2*x3, x3^4 - 1};

x02 = {.1, .1, .1};

x01 = {-.01, -0.01, -0.01};

tolerance =10^-9;

(J = Table[
Table[D[f[x1, x2, x3][[i]], xi], {xi, {x1, x2, x3}}], {i, 1, 
 3}]) // MatrixForm

Jac[{xa_, xb_, xc_}] := J /. {x1 -> xa, x2 -> xb, x3 -> xc} ;

Jac[{x1, x2, x3}];

Inverse[Jac[{x1, x2, x3}]] // MatrixForm
```

How to write a code for the Newton method and Armijo-Goldstein to see and compare the results?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that your `J` can be defined more simply as `J = D[f[x1, x2, x3], {{x1, x2, x3}}]`

Answer (score 1):

Armijo-Goldstein is a stopping criteria for the backtracking line search implemented in `FindMinimum` and can be used as follows

```
f = {x1^5 + x2^3*x3^4 + 1, x1^2*x2*x3, x3^4 - 1};

x02 = {.1, .1, .1};

x01 = {-.01, -0.01, -0.01};

tolerance = 10^-9;

sol1 = FindMinimum[f . f, Table[{x[[i]], x01[[i]]}, {i, 3}], 
  Method -> {"Newton", 
    "StepControl" -> {"LineSearch", Method -> "Backtracking"}}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 10] 
{3.83291*10^-33, {x1 -> 7.86832*10^-9, x2 -> -1., x3 -> -1.}}
```

If we use directly `FindRoot` with `Newton` then we have

```
sol01=FindRoot[f, Table[{x[[i]], x01[[i]]}, {i, 3}], 
 Method -> "Newton"]

During evaluation of In[15]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

Out[15]= {x1 -> -0.462688, x2 -> 0.901034, x3 -> -0.0156579}
```

Therefore, Newton's iterative method not working in this case without step control. We can check residuals for Armijo-Goldstein

```
f /. sol1[[2]]

Out[]= {0., 6.19105*10^-17, 0.}
```

and for the Newton's iterative method

```
f /. sol01

Out[]= {0.978795, -0.00302031, -1.}
```

To improve Newton's method we can use sol1 as starting point

```
sol01n=FindRoot[f, Table[{x[[i]], x[[i]] /. sol1[[2]]}, {i, 3}]]

Out[]= {x1 -> 3.93416*10^-9, x2 -> -1., x3 -> -1.}
```